# "Обёртка" методов в C#

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть определённый класс. В ряде методов этого класса первая и последняя строки одинаковые. Есть ли какой-то элегантный способ где-то написать их только один раз и использовать их как обёртку для этих методов, чтобы не дублировать каждый раз код в методах? Пусть даже займёт больше строк кода, главное, чтобы была возможность изменить код только в одном месте, и логика работы поменялась бы у всех таких методов. Ниже пример двух методов.

```
public bool Draw(int firstLine = 1, int lastLine = 180) 
{
    if (!this.Connected || drv == null) return false; //////

    drv.FirstLineNumber = firstLine;
    drv.LastLineNumber = lastLine;
    OperationResult = drv.Draw();

    return OperationResult == 0 ? true : false; //////
}

public bool XReport()
{
    if (!this.Connected || drv == null) return false; //////

    OperationResult = drv.PrintReportWithoutCleaning();

    return OperationResult == 0 ? true : false; //////
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
public bool Draw(int firstLine = 1, int lastLine = 180)
{
    return RunWithDrv(() =>
    {
        drv.FirstLineNumber = firstLine;
        drv.LastLineNumber = lastLine;
        return drv.Draw();
    });
}

public bool XReport()
{
    return RunWithDrv(drv.PrintReportWithoutCleaning);
}

public bool RunWithDrv(Func<int> action)
{
    if (!this.Connected || drv == null) return false; //////

    OperationResult = action();

    return OperationResult == 0 ? true : false; //////
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно глянуть в сторону аспектно-ориентированного программирования: AspectSharp, [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/)